# Firebase Functions can't find pug

Tags: node.js, firebase, pug, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple firebase function that renders a pug template.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const creds = {
    projectId: "retnikt-blog",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n REDACTED \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    clientEmail: "REDACTED@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
};

admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.cert(creds)});
const app = require("express")();
const pug = require("pug");
app.engine('pug', pug.__express);
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', '../views');

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.render('blog.pug', {
        title: 'title',
        body: 'body',
        author: 'author',
        date: 'date',
        categories: 'categories',
        tags: 'tags'
    });
});
```

When I run this function it tells me `Error: Cannot find module 'pug'`. I have installed pug with NPM in my project's root directory, and in my `package.json` dependencies I have specified pug:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "pug": "2.0.3"
}
```

I installed Pug globally and now it works locally, but when I deploy it just gives "Error: could not handle the request" with a 500 status.

My two questions are:
A) Why is the installed pug not being recognised,
and
<del>B) Is the "could not handle the request" also because of pug not being recognised?</del>

**EDIT**: After checking the logs it appears this is correct

NodeJs v8.10.0
firebase-tools 3.18.5

Answer (score 1):

pug must be a dependency on you package.json inside the functions folder, not in the root folder.